# Drop tables in bulk without using cursor

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I want to drop all tables that are coming from this query.There can be multiple tables.

This query will return the tables names of my stage database.

```
SELECT name FROM sys.objects WHERE create_date < GETDATE()-7
```

How can I drop tables without using cursor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to obtain the names of all tables which are 7 days older or more..

```
SELECT name FROM sys.tables WHERE DATEDIFF(day,create_date,GETDATE()) >= 7
```

sys.objects is not for tables its for objects you should use sys.tables

and the cursorless deletion..

USE AT YOUR OWN RISK

```
BEGIN TRAN
DECLARE @DropTables NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @DropTables = ''

SELECT @DropTables = @DropTables + 
    'DROP TABLE '+name+CHAR(10)
FROM sys.tables 
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,create_date,GETDATE()) >= 7
EXEC(@DropTables)
ROLLBACK
```